# Transform not getting applied on CustomDataset Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I images with folder structure as following :

```
root_dir
│
└───folder1
│   │   file011.png
│   │   file012.png
│   
└───folder2
|   │   file021.png
|   │   file022.png
|
└───folder2
    │   file031.png
    │   file032.png
...
```

Now I wanted to create a CustomeDataset without labels in PyTorch (since I am using it for GANs)
So I did the following :

```py
class CurrencyDataset(Dataset):
    '''
    Currency Dataset with no labels
    '''
    def __init__(self, type, transform):
        '''
        Parameters
            type : "Train" or "Test"
            transform : Transformations to be applied 
        '''
        root_dir = "indian-currency-notes-classifier/" 
        # Storing images in a list
        self.data = []
        self.transform = transform
        dir = os.path.join(root_dir, type)
        for note in os.listdir(dir) :
            note_dir = os.path.join(dir, note)
            for img_name in os.listdir(note_dir):
                img = io.imread(os.path.join(note_dir, img_name))
                self.data.append(img)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
        
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        x = self.data[idx]
        if self.transform :
            x = self.transform(x)
        return x
```

and used the following transformations :

```py
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
    transforms.RandomRotation(15),
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

train_ds = CurrencyDataset("Train", transform)
```

but on checking the shape and values of the Tensors, I found out that transformations were not getting applied

```py
train_ds.data[0].shape
>> (1072, 1154, 3)
```

I am a bit new to PyTorch so please let me know If I am doing something wrong here or What needs to be done to make it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the `transform` object as an attribute of the instance. This, in turn, means `self.transform` evaluates to `None` in the `__getitem__` function. Simply add the following in the `__init__`:

```
self.transform = transform
```

---

Additonally, you are not calling the proper function (`__getitem__`) with `train_ds.data[0].shape`, instead it should be `train_ds[0]` (in other words: `train_ds.__getitem__(0)`).

---

Finally, your pipeline doesn't have the correct order of transforms as `T.Resize` expects a `torch.Tensor`, not a PIL image:

```
transform = T.Compose([
    T.RandomRotation(15),
    T.Resize((224, 224)),
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])
```

Comment: I tried this too but that too doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @PATHIKGHUGARE Can you update your question with that modification? What is the output in this case?

Comment: yup I updated the question but Its the same output as before, can you check it here if possible? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bDc2Qqpdk1Nk2WciymsZKA35zoDLVHHh?usp=sharing

Comment: @PATHIKGHUGARE I think I found the issue, see my edit above.

Comment: I tried your order of transformation and as you said to use ```train_ds[0]``` instead of using ```train_ds.data[0]```, I tried that too but it gave me an error that says : ```TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>```

Comment: So additionally at the beginning of .Compose() I added a ```transforms.ToPILImage()``` and now it is working fine. Thank you so much @Ivan

Comment: No worries @PATHIKGHUGARE. Alternatively, you can remove the ToTensor and ToPILImage transforms altogether since the input is a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be the order of your transformations. Could you try this out?

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.RandomRotation(15),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
])
```